# Network alias for wlan devices

Tags: networking, udev, symbolic-link

I would like to create a symbolic link in /sys/class/net where   apN  points to the same location as wlanN.

I have tried many things (udev rules)  ... but haven't been able to get this to work.

The reason is so that I can have different configuration info in /etc/network/interfaces for   apN and wlanN

Comment: It depends if you are really using `/etc/network/interfaces`. If your computer has NetworkManager enabled, it disable any settings you type at that file.  What is your Ubuntu release?

Comment: I am not using  Network Manager ... no gui for config.

Comment: We only support Ubuntu here. Sorry.

Comment: I am running Ubunto on an ODroid

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No easy solution to this without kernel modification.

- Linux kernel controls SYSFS tree `/sys/..`.
- Udev uses `SYMLINK` action only for device nodes in DEVFS `/dev/..` which not the case for network interfaces.